# What are these kinds of pins called?

Tags: pins, chassis

What are these connectors at the edge of the chassis called? I thought they were pogo pins, but it seems like they're not uniform and are keyed? How well do these kinds of connectors stand up to repeated mating?

[image: Board edge connectors]

Comment: I don't see any connectors. Those blurry dots at the edge?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm talking about the gold coloured ones (two sets of 6 dots) along the bottom and left edges.

Comment: Well, I can't see a *** thing. There are various spring-loaded connectors that could contact something like that, maybe, depending on what it actually looks like.

Comment: You leave off the name of the device, which would help in figuring out the connectors used.

Comment: why do I feel like Joshi is pulling a fast one with a Where's Waldo exercise on the connector while this prototype has an optical illusion with different keys and difference matrix patterns.

Comment: This is what you get when you cross an Amphenol, a DIN and a Hirosi connector. 3 pairs and the fat ones stick out first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Impossible to tell by sight, but they could very well be "Magnetic Self Locating" connectors. As with many other things, used by and popularized by Apple, but not invented by them.

Just wild speculation, but it looks like there could be three "female" pins interleaved with three "male" pins which would make the connectors "hermaphroditic".  It would be very revealing to see the mating connector.

EDIT: Upon closer inspection, it looks like there are four modules linked together via those connectors. So I believe I am correct that they are both magnetic and 6-pin interleaved hermaphroditic.

It is not clear whether those blue lights seen in the photo are an additional optical communication method, or some sort of human indicicator, or perhaps just decorative. In any case, very nice looking modules and industrial design. I like it a lot.

Comment: I agree with the "hermaphroditic" and the mating connector by "definition" would  be identical and is shown with two units paired to each other while giving the illusion of a matrix of mobiles wired together with an example of two of out infinite possible connections in theory.

Comment: The pins appear to be gold-plated which would make them lresistant to corrosion. And presumably the "male" pins are slightly spring-loaded (like "pogo-pins") to hold firm physical contact despite slight mechanical variations.  But I would be somewhat concerned about the vulnerability of the protruding pins. That scheme would be suitable for careful indoor applications, but not very rugged in more hazardous outdoor situations.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they are custom made using spring loaded pins such as the ones Mill Max makes (commonly referred to as pogo pins). Check out products from [Cotelec](http://www.cotelec.fr/connectique-a-ressort/) too. I think they make something similar.

Comment: I would agree. A rigid case needs spring force contacts with pins and socket types to be mechanically sound and anaphrodic